# use of unresolved identifier error and csv error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, csv, parsing

I've been stuck on this for the past couple days. I've made progress on other things in my project but this is holding me back, now i'm at the point where I need to somehow overcome this. Anyways, I've posted a question before about this but I guess I need to be way more specific.

My issue is I need to be able to search through this .CSV file using the barcode and return all the information regarding it. I've done this successfully in c++ but don't know why i'm having so much difficulties in swift.

This is a part of the file (has about 150 in total):

```
TITLE,SKU,PRICE,Barcode,WEIGHT,BOX HEIGHT,BOX W_IDTH,BOX LENGTH

"No.27 Grapefruit Triple Scented Soy Candle, 7oz",EBWC-10027,72,6933083850573,4,14.8,29.1,20.4

"No.18 Green Tea Jasmine Triple Scented Soy Candle, 7oz",EBWC-10018,72,6933083850580,4,14.8,29.1,20.4
```

Here is what i've done:

```
 static func searchCode(codeNumber: String) -> [(title:String, sku:String, price:String, barcodeNum:String, weight:String, box_height:String, box_width:String, box_length:String )]?
    {


        //let test = "6933083850771"
        let characterNumber = codeNumber.characters.count
        //var dataArray = [Data]()
        let barcodeNumber = codeNumber
        if let remoteURL = NSURL(string: downloadconstants.URLConstants.productfile ){
            while let line: String = barcodeNumber{
                // Load the CSV file and parse it
                let delimiter = ","
                var items:[(title:String, sku:String, price:String, barcodeNum:String, weight:String, box_height:String, box_width:String, box_length:String )]?

                do {
                    let content = try String(codeNumber)
                    print(content)
                    items = []
                    let lines:[String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String]

                    for line in lines {
                        var values:[String] = []
                        if line != "" {
                            // For a line with double quotes
                            // we use NSScanner to perform the parsing
                            if line.rangeOfString("\"") != nil {
                                var textToScan:String = line
                                var value:NSString?
                                var textScanner:NSScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                                while textScanner.string != "" {

                                    if (textScanner.string as NSString).substringToIndex(1) == "\"" {
                                        textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                                        textScanner.scanUpToString("\"", intoString: &value)
                                        textScanner.scanLocation += 1
                                    } else {
                                        textScanner.scanUpToString(delimiter, intoString: &value)
                                    }

                                    // Store the value into the values array
                                    values.append(value as! String)

                                    // Retrieve the unscanned remainder of the string
                                    if textScanner.scanLocation < textScanner.string.characters.count {
                                        textToScan = (textScanner.string as NSString).substringFromIndex(textScanner.scanLocation + 1)
                                    } else {
                                        textToScan = ""
                                    }
                                    textScanner = NSScanner(string: textToScan)
                                }

                                // For a line without double quotes, we can simply separate the string
                                // by using the delimiter (e.g. comma)
                            } else  {
                                values = line.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter)
                            }

                            // Put the values into the tuple and add it to the items array
                            let item = (title: values[0], sku: values[1], price: values[2], barcodeNum: values[3], weight: values[4], box_height: values[5], box_width: values[6], box_length: values[7])
                            items?.append(item)
                        }
                    }

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }



            }
        }
        //Error: Use of unresolved identifier "items"
        return items
    }
```

I'm getting an error on the return. I've read online a bit, but no luck. Also for what I need my function to do what should be changed to make it work?

Comment: After just quickly looking over the code, I noticed that your "return items" is throwing an error due to it being too far down in the function. What I mean is this: the var "items" is being initialized in your first while block which is fine, but in doing so, that variable isn't available as a return type for the whole function. Moving it from where it is to just below your catch statement removes that error, however, without testing it more I can't say it'll fully fix your issue.

Comment: @DemonicPenguin Thanks! What you said worked, I had to move it outside of my while block and it worked. Would you know how I am able to fix it to show all the information regarding the barcode being searched?

Comment: Not a problem! I'm not sure I quite understand what you're looking for, what information is that code returning at the moment?

Comment: @DemonicPenguin the barcode is being passed from another function, I am trying to search through the file using the barcode, then to display and return all the information on that tuple when the barcode is found. But right now while i'm debugging it no data is getting stored into the arrays thus nothing is getting returned. Can't seem to figure out why.